# jquery my done callback gets only called one time i dont get why

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
/**
 * Downloads the fingerprint preview data 
 */
this.fetchFingerprintPreviews = function (url) {
    var that = this;
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

    jQuery.get(url)
        .done(function (resp) {
            var linkNodes = conn.getLinksViaRelation(resp,  
            'http://ws.bdr.de/webhd/hdcap/rels/finger-preview/');

            jQuery(linkNodes).each(function () {
                var link = jQuery(this);
                var fpIndex = link.prev("index, bdr\\:index").html();
                var fpType = link.attr('type');

                jQuery.get(link.attr('href'), {"encoding":"base64"}, null, "text")
                    .done(function (imageDataBase64) {
                        fingerprintPreview[fpIndex] = {};
                        fingerprintPreview[fpIndex].imageData = imageDataBase64;
                        fingerprintPreview[fpIndex].type = fpType;

                        console.log(fingerprintPreview);
                        if (Object.keys(fingerprintPreview).length == 
                        Object.keys(linkNodes).length) {
                            dfd.resolve();
                        }
                    });

            });
        });

    return dfd;
}
```

a new version added which makes use of lexical local variables. still not working.
m a bit lost at the moment...
also added a log statement which gets called only one time.
i would expect the log to get called two times.

any ideas?

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: but on the console i even see two request going out. all returning with 200

Comment: jquery version 1.9 here (primefaces)

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that your done callback is called once, but that you change the same  `fingerprintPreview` each time it is called because `that` has the value of end of loop when the callbaks are called.

The solution is to not reuse this externally declared variable but a new one, declared in the function you give to `each` :

```
jQuery(linkNodes).each(function () {
    var link = jQuery(this);
    var fpIndex = link.prev("index, bdr\\:index").html();
    var fpType = link.attr('type');

    jQuery.get(link.attr('href'), {"encoding":"base64"}, null, "text")
        .done(function (imageDataBase64) {
            fingerprintPreview[fpIndex] = {};
            fingerprintPreview[fpIndex].imageData = imageDataBase64;
            fingerprintPreview[fpIndex].type = fpType;

            if (Object.keys(fingerprintPreview).length == Object.keys(linkNodes).length) {
                alert("foo");
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: added my new function code. breakpoint gets called only one time. but i see two http calls in the comsole log.

Answer (score 0):

i found out what the problem was. dystroys answer is correct but was not adressing my original problem. so the thing is that when i have a firebug breakpoint in my done function callback it will be called only one time. so having breakpoints set with firebug can lead to uninterpreted js code... ffs!